# Lack of a closing </sub> in a paragraph results in a later <sub></sub> pair not being applied

Tags: bug, status-review, markdown-rendering

On the question [How to convert a string of space- and comma- separated numbers into a list of int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334374)

Note the comment I have added at the end of the page source. If I try to remove the comment and its enclosing `<sub></sub>` tags, the last paragraph of the note reverts (in both the preview and the submitted version) to normal size, as if its enclosing tags were not there.

There is no analogous issue on any other question; for example see [How to split a string of space separated numbers into integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429638) whence I copied the note. (I reopened the first question, previously marked duplicate of the second, because of the additional consideration: numbers separated by `,`  are better off split by `,` rather than `,` , because it is more fault-tolerant as `int` will tolerate the leading space.)

### Example

#### Correct rendering of CommonMark Markdown

[Live example on CommonMark site, showing both paragraphs in subscript](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=%3Csub%3EParagraph%20in%20subscript%20without%20closing%20%60%3C%2Fsub%3E%60%0A%0A%3Csub%3EParagraph%20that%27s%20supposed%20to%20be%20in%20subscript%2C%20but%20isn%27t.%3C%2Fsub%3E%0A)

#### Incorrect rendering on Stack Exchange

##### Markdown text

```markdown
<sub>Paragraph in subscript without closing `</sub>`

<sub>Paragraph that's supposed to be in subscript, but isn't.</sub>
```

##### Incorrect rendered text (in both the editing preview and once saved)

Paragraph in subscript without closing `</sub>`

Paragraph that's supposed to be in subscript, but isn't.

Comment: The first paragraph in your note is missing a `</sub>`. While that shouldn't matter, as can be tested on the [CommonMark test site](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=%3Csub%3Esub%20without%20%60%3C%2Fsub%3E%60%0A%0A%3Csub%3EIs%20sub%3C%2Fsub%3E), it does matter on SE, at least in the preview. It might be something to do with SE's HTML tag stripping (which is supposed to just strip HTML tags that aren't in the list of allowed tags).

Comment: @Makyen Ah! Good eye. I updated to fix that, and it works fine now.

Comment: This is actually a bug, which should be reported. At a minimum, the behavior should be clearly documented in [answer to: "What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/271271). Either way, we should report it to SE to have them tell us if it's working the way they intend.